# Why do I get a different number of methods after proguard using maven and gradle

Tags: android, proguard

I have a project with with a big number of third party libraries.
So I use pro-guard.
I build project using maven. 
After migrating project to gradle I get error:
"trouble writing output: Too many method references: 66062; max is 65536."

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure ProGuard is enabled? Can you show us your Gradle build file?

Comment: yes. because if ProGuard wasn't enabled I couldn't build project even in debug mode.

Comment: I have no idea how to find what I do different

Comment: I'm guessing that your dependencies (or more likely your transitive dependencies) are different after the migration. You can use `mvn dependency:tree` and `gradle dependencies` to compare.

Comment: Try running `gradle clean assembleDebug -d` to see if there are any warnings related to Proguard